# Display object property in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to display the property "Title" from a list of objects in a ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableSurveysByYear}"
         DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Title}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSurvey}">
```

However, instead of the titles, all I see is the *name* of my class, three times. SelectableSurveysByYear is an ObservableCollection of Surveys:

```
public class Survey
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Where is my flaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayMemberPath` property doesn't support the `Binding` syntax. Try the following:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableSurveysByYear}"
     DisplayMemberPath="Title" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSurvey}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. the flaw was in defining DisplayMemberPath. This works:

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableSurveysByYear}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSurvey}">
```